# С++ Web интерфейс для приложения

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, frontend, backend

У меня C++ консольное приложение работает на несколько потоков и в дополнение к этому, построено на boost::asio.
Есть потребность в реализации интерфейса, который можно будет открыть через мобильный/desktop браузер, посмотреть статистику и даже отправлять какие-то сигналы через кнопки моему приложению.
Изначально думал использовать Wt, но показалось, что он не очень гибкий, да и к тому же, лучше логику фронта и бэкэнда разделить.

Как лучше всего реализовать подобную идею и (или) куда копать?

Comment: может вы напишете свой сайт apache php ? не осилите ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe осилить то можно всё, вопрос только, как мне реализовать это так, чтобы это запускалось одновременно с моим консольным приложением и как apache+php будут общаться с моим C++ приложением?

Comment: boost.beast же есть